# Swap two elements in a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, swap

I write this method for swapping two elements in a 2D array:

```
    public void swap(Object[][] array, int a, int b) {
    Object temp;
    temp = array[a];
    array[a] = array[b];
    array[b] = temp; // Error, Why?
}
```

But there is a compile time error in last line.

For example, i want to swap `array[i][j+1]` and `array[i+1][j]` elements, How should call this method?

(`i` and `j` are int in for loop)

**update**

Should i swap by element-based ? Or by index-based?

How should be my parameters in `swap` array?

**Update 2**

```
    public void swap(Object[][] array, int i1, int j1, int i2, int j2) {
    Object tempObject = array[i1][j1];
    array[i1][j1] = array[i2][j2];
    array[i2][j2] = tempObject;
}
```

Is this correct for swapping arbitrary elements of a 2D array?

Comment: what does the error say?

Comment: @SamIam `Found Object` required `Object[]`

Comment: I'm not sure what your distinction is between "element-based" and "index-based".  You can use both your indexes to swap the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `a` and `b` as only one coordinate each into a 2D array, so `array[a]` and `array[b]` refer to the arrays representing the rows `a` and `b`, not the individual elements.

The error arises when you attempt to assign an `Object` to an `Object[]` (`array[b]`) on your last line.

Use both `a` and `b` as your `i` and `j` explanation indicates.

```
Object temp = array[a][b + 1];
array[a][b + 1] = array[a + 1][b];
array[a + 1][b] = temp;
```

Comment: I want to use this single `swap()` method for all swaps of `array[i][j+1]` and `array[i+1][j]` , second `array[i+1][j]` and `array[i][j]` , Third `array[i][j-1]` and `array[i][j]` .

Comment: Your method works just for `array[i][j+1]` and `array[i+1][j]` , How should changes?

Comment: That's all you specified originally.  If you want two sets of arbitrary coordinates, then you'll need two additional `int` parameters in your `swap` method, so that you can swap any two elements at any arbitrary positions `[a][b]` and `[c][d]`.

Answer (score 1):

One Liner:

```
(array[a][b + 1], array[b][a + 1]) = (array[b][a + 1], array[a + 1][b])
```